# Find dependence of $\theta$ with $x$ and $\Delta x$.If $f(x) = e^x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Using this formula $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)=\frac{df}{dx}(x+\theta \Delta x)*\Delta x$ ($0<\theta<1$)

Find dependence of $\theta$ with $x$ and $\Delta x$.If $f(x) = e^x$.

My work.

$e^{x+\Delta x}$  $- e^x$ = $e^{x+\theta \Delta x}$ $\Delta x$

$e^{x+\theta \Delta x}$ = $\frac{e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x}{\Delta x}$

$\theta$ = $\frac{ln(\frac{e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x}{\Delta x})-x}{\Delta x}$

but the answer is $\theta = \frac{1}{\Delta x}$ $ln\frac{e^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}$

Comment: The two answers are the same for $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(ln(\frac{e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x}{\Delta x})-x\right) = \frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(ln(\frac{e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x}{\Delta x})-ln(e^x)\right)=\frac{1}{\Delta x}ln(\frac{e^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x})$$